# Extracting a substring in R

Tags: r

I know this topic has been addressed before, but I'm still having trouble.

I have a string:

```
string<-"abcd-ef-2805"
```

I would like to isolate the number "2805" and get rid of the rest.

Similarly, I have another string:

```
string2<-"ABCD.EF.2805.03A.0IT.0734.13"
```

Again, I would like to isolate "2805" and get rid of the rest.

Thanks.

Comment: are you always looking for 2805? Or this just a bad example? Because you could just do something like `regmatches(string, regexpr("2805", string))`

Comment: You need to explain what makes 2805 the expected result. Is it the first number? The first 4-digit number? ...?

Comment: They are always 4 digits, but do not always begin with 2. I would prefer a solution that extracts the value based on it's location in the string, which never changes across samples.

Comment: Apparently you are looking for the `substr` function, which extracts substrings based on position?

Comment: `substr(string2, 9, 12)` Fixed location.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Vlo, your suggestion worked great

Answer (score 2):

With the `stringr` package:

```
  str_extract(string2,"[0-9]+")
```

This will extract the first numeric sequence. As per your edit, if the sequence is always of 4 digits, it's better:

```
  str_extract(string2,"[0-9]{4}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the location never changes and your example above is relevant you could just do :

```
string<-"abcd-ef-2805"
a<-unlist(strsplit(string,"-"))
a[3]

string2<-"ABCD.EF.2805.03A.0IT.0734.13" 
b<-unlist(strsplit(string2,"[.]"))
b[3]
```